# How to loop into Excel file row in Java Poi

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, while-loop, apache-poi

I'm trying to loop into my Excel rows using the row.hasNext() but only loop once and return the 1st row only. (I'm using eclipse btw.)

This is my Excel (.xlsm) file:

```
BILLOFLADING || REFERENCENUMBER || PURCHASEORDERNUMBER... and so on
4621002      || 7672784         || BLAZER .... and so on
4621001      || 7672914         || CG605515.... and so on
..some more rows here..
```

This is my code:

```
String filename = "C:\\Users\\myExcel.xlsm";
    String batchRunNbr = convertDateToString(new Date(), "yyMMddHHmmSS");

    List sheetData = new ArrayList();
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator();
        int counter = 0;
        while (rows.hasNext()) {
            counter++;
            log.info("COUNTER>"+counter);
            Row row = rows.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator();

            List data = new ArrayList();
            while (cells.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cells.next();
                data.add(cell);
            }

            sheetData.add(data);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (fis != null) {
            fis.close();
        }
    }

    showExcelData(sheetData, batchRunNbr);
    return 0;
}

private void showExcelData(List sheetData, String batchRunNbr) throws ParseException {

     DataFormatter formatter2 = new DataFormatter();
    DateFormat formatter;
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
    boolean firstTime = true;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sheetData.size(); i++) {
        List list = (List) sheetData.get(i);

        if (firstTime) {
            firstTime = false;

        }else{
            count++;
            log.info("VALUE OF R>"+count);
        for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
            Cell cell = (Cell) list.get(j);

                if ((cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) || (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)){

                switchCase(formatter, i, cell);


            } else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) {
                System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
            }
            if (j < list.size() - 1) {
                i++;
                System.out.print("\t");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("");


        //this code is an sql statement to insert to the database using hibernate
        insertToStaging(batchRunNbr);




        }
    }
    log.info("Completed!");
}
```

And this is my **switchCase()** method to allign the cell values:

```
switch (i) {

    case 1:
        this.billOfLading = formatNumber(Double.toString(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
        log.info(i+"="+this.billOfLading);
        break;
    case 2:
        this.referenceNbr = formatNumber(Double.toString(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
        log.info(i+"="+this.referenceNbr);
        break;
    case 3:
        this.purchaseOrderNbr = formatText(cell.getStringCellValue());
        log.info(i+"="+this.purchaseOrderNbr);
        break;
    case 4:
        this.sku = formatText(cell.getStringCellValue());
        log.info(i+"="+this.sku);
        break;
..and so on...
```

This is my **formatText()** and **formatNumber()** methods to add single quotes or null values to each cell.

```
    private String formatText(String s) {
    if ((s != null) && (s.trim().length() > 0)){
        s = "'" + s + "'";
    } else {
        s = "null";
    }
    return s;
}

private String formatNumber(String s) {

    if ((s != null) && (s.trim().length() > 0)) {
        return s;
    } else {
        s = "0";
    }

    return s;
}
```

And my result is looping only once..

```
main 2016/11/17 14:47:33:618 INFO  com....(234) - COUNTER>1
main 2016/11/17 14:47:33:622 INFO  com....(234) - COUNTER>2
main 2016/11/17 14:47:33:622 INFO  com....(234) - COUNTER>3
main 2016/11/17 14:47:33:622 INFO  com....(234) - COUNTER>4
main 2016/11/17 14:47:33:627 INFO  com....(283) - VALUE OF R>1
main 2016/11/17 14:47:33:632 INFO  com....(349) - 1=4621002.0
    main 2016/11/17 14:47:33:632 INFO  com....(354) - 2=7672784.0
    main 2016/11/17 14:47:33:635 INFO  com....(359) - 3='BLAZER'
    main 2016/11/17 14:47:33:636 INFO  com....(364) - 4='CT101_6X48_FL_852'
    main 2016/11/17 14:47:33:636 INFO  com....(370) - 5=9.0
    main 2016/11/17 14:47:33:647 INFO  com....(383) - 6='2016-11-14 00:00:00'
    main 2016/11/17 14:47:33:648 INFO  com....(388) - 7='DEJ'
    main 2016/11/17 14:47:33:648 INFO  com....(393) - 8='LTL'
    main 2016/11/17 14:47:33:649 INFO  com....(398) - 9='Prepaid'
    main 2016/11/17 14:47:33:650 INFO  com....(403) - 10='FRYS FLOORING, LLC'
    main 2016/11/17 14:47:33:650 INFO  com....(408) - 11=null
    main 2016/11/17 14:47:33:651 INFO  com....(413) - 12='7 E MAIN STREET'
    main 2016/11/17 14:47:33:651 INFO  com....(418) - 13='ELIZABETHVILLE'
    main 2016/11/17 14:47:33:652 INFO  com....(423) - 14='PA'
    main 2016/11/17 14:47:33:652 INFO  com....(428) - 15='17023'
    main 2016/11/17 14:47:33:653 INFO  com....(433) - 16='US'
    main 2016/11/17 14:47:33:653 INFO  com....(438) - 17='7173626987'
    main 2016/11/17 14:47:33:654 INFO  com....(443) - 18=null
    main 2016/11/17 14:47:33:654 INFO  com....(448) - 19='T lot number'
    main 2016/11/17 14:47:33:655 INFO  com....(457) - 20='284392'
```

Comment: You mean you want the loop to enter every line but it's only entering the last line? What do you want to achieve? I see the row counter is increasing (1, 2, 3, 4....)

Comment: yeah.. I want the result to loop 3  times because i have 3 record rows on my excel. and I want that result to change each loop depending on the rows. sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (j < list.size() - 1) {
    i++;
    System.out.print("\t");
}
```

This part is constantly increasing the row index (`i`). If you are in a `for` loop nesting another `for` loop, it's not necessary.

If you have 5 rows and 4 cells, for example, when looping in the first row, `j < list.size() - 1` will be true for 3 times and `i` will be increased for 3 times (1, 2, 3), and you move to the fourth line when you quit the inner loop, so the lines in-between are skipped.

Comment: oh.. i see.. but when i remove my `i++;` the `i` counter will not increment and the result is this..

`1=4621002.0
1=7672784.0
1=BLAZER1
.......`

Comment: Let's see. You want to print the whole array?

Comment: I really don't know how to arrange my codes now its confusing me.

Comment: yes.. I'm confused now with my looping and can't focus anymore @_@ it took me 2 days now and still can't figure it out.

Comment: It happens a lot to me too. Try to debug into every line. It's not a large project and has few lines.

Comment: Thanks. I'll just try to recreate it again and let see what happens. lol

Comment: I think debugging is the best way. Recreating it would make you fall into the same pit twice, and you never know where you did wrong last time. You'll have to debug the new program, at last.

Comment: I suspect the `switchCase(formatter, i, cell);` should be `switchCase(formatter, j, cell);` since `j` is the cell counter within the inner `for` while `i` is the row counter within the outer `for`. Then try without manipulating the `i` within the `for` loop which uses `i` as counter.

Comment: Edit: I finally got it working.. looping 3 times now. I will edit my post above based on my new changes. Thank you so much @AxelRichter and FaithReaper

Comment: If edited, the original question may not stand anymore. Considering accept one answer.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Changes to solve the problem:

1. I changed this  code `switchCase(formatter, i, cell);` to `switchCase(formatter, j, cell);`
2. I removed the `i++;`

From..

```
if (j < list.size() - 1) {
    i++;            
    System.out.print("\t");
}
```

To..

```
if (j < list.size() - 1) {  
        System.out.print("\t");
    }
```

Comment: No worries @Martin. If you want to post it again in your own name then let me know, and I will delete this one.